# Firing DOM mouse events programmatically from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, mouse

Is it possible to programmatically fire mouse events in DOM? My sample case would be the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" src="something.html"></iframe>
    <div id="layer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top=0px; width=500px; height=500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever the user clicks the `div` over an `iframe`, I would like to somehow propagate the event to the `iframe`, too. (Here we assume that the `iframe src` is in the same domain.)

Comment: you could do it in jQuery - $("div#layer").click(); of course you would need to pre-bind the click event - $('div#layer').click(somefunc())

Comment: Doesn't work because I need the events to propagate to the `iframe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you *can* inject events into browsers' event-handling systems (in not entirely portable ways), it will only cause event handlers registered on those events to be called. It won't cause default actions like following clicked links. Also you don't get the target element worked out for you from co-ordinates so you'd have to do that yourself.

A better bet would be to lose the obscuring `<div>` and register a `click` handler on the iframe's document, which then informs code in the parent of the location of the click.

Comment: ...unless the iframe *src* is a different domain, in which case you're out of luck :-)

Comment: Added a note about being in the same domain.

Comment: Alright, so the best solution was to register an onclick handler for the iframe content's `document.body`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever are in a situation, where you have `<iframe>`s parent and child in different domains, I recommend learning to use `postMessage()`.

With `postMessage()` you can listen `"message"`event like so:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

I wanted to add this, because a while back, I had a hard time finding the best way to do it. Also, `postMessage()` is useful in situations, when you want to control things, you want to listen in an iframe.